# 'protractor-cucumber-js-reportingFeature'-Unhandled rejection TypeError: registerHandler is not a function

Tags: typescript, protractor, cucumberjs

Please help me:

What is the best way for cuumberHtmlReporting?
is there any compatible issues?
For the latest version how to use the reporting feature?

Please help

Thanks

---

**config.ts   Main config File:**

```
import{browser,Config} from 'protractor'

export const config:Config ={

allScriptsTimeout: 500000, //This is the overall Timeout
getPageTimeout: 500000,

seleniumAddress: "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub",

    SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,

    capabilities: {
        browserName:"chrome"
    },



    suites:{
        "DefaultBookMark":["../features/bCDfeature"],
       // "CreateDraft":["../features/ABC.feature"]


    },
    framework:"custom",
    frameworkPath:require.resolve("protractor-cucumber-framework"),
    onPrepare: () => {


        browser.manage().window().maximize();


       browser.waitForAngularEnabled();



    },



    cucumberOpts: {
        compiler: "ts:ts-node/register",
        require: ["../Sprint1/steps/ABC.ts","../hooks/support.ts"],

        strict: true,
        tags: "@smoke",
        format:'pretty'



    },


    // onComplete:()=>{
    //     browser.close();
    // }
}
```

**hooks.ts  -hooks file:**

```
const Cucumber = require('cucumber');
import { browser } from 'protractor';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import { config } from '../config/config';
import { defineSupportCode } from "cucumber";
import * as reporter from 'cucumber-html-reporter';
import { mkdirp } from 'mkdirp';
import{Md5} from 'ts-md5/dist/md5'

defineSupportCode(function ({ registerHandler, registerListener, After, setDefaultTimeout,Before }) {
setDefaultTimeout(10 * 4000);
let jsonReports = process.cwd() + "/reports/json";
let htmlReports = process.cwd() + "/reports/html";
let targetJson = jsonReports + "/cucumber_report.json";
let screenshots = process.cwd() + "/reports/images/";

registerHandler('BeforeFeature', async function () {
    await browser.get(config.baseUrl);
});



registerHandler('AfterStep', async(event) => {

   if (event.name) {
     let featurename = event.scenario.name

        // if(event.name.toString().le
        //     {
        //         var stepname = event.name.replace("BiGFILENAME");
        //     }else
        //     {
        //         var stepname = event.name;
        //     }


     if (!fs.existsSync(screenshots)) {
       mkdirp.sync(screenshots);
     }
     let screenShot = await browser.takeScreenshot();
     var timeInMs = Date.now();
     var stream = fs.createWriteStream(screenshots + featurename+"_"+timeInMs+".png");
     stream.write(new Buffer(screenShot, 'base64'));
     stream.end();
   }

});

After(async (scenarioResult) => {
    let world = this;
    if (scenarioResult.status=="FAILED") {
        let screenShot = await browser.takeScreenshot();
        // screenShot is a base-64 encoded PNG
        world.attach(screenShot, 'image/png');
    }
})


let cucumberReporterOptions = {
    theme: "bootstrap",
    jsonFile: targetJson,
    output: htmlReports + "/cucumber_reporter.html",
    reportSuiteAsScenarios: true
};

let logFn = string => {
    if (!fs.existsSync(jsonReports)) {
        mkdirp.sync(jsonReports);
    }
    try {
        fs.writeFileSync(targetJson, string);
        reporter.generate(cucumberReporterOptions); // invoke cucumber-html-reporter
    } catch (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(`Failed to save cucumber test results to json file. 
                         Failed to create html report.
                         `);
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
};
let jsonformatter = new Cucumber.JsonFormatter({
    log: logFn
});
registerListener(jsonformatter);
})
```

**dev dependencies  packages:**

```
"devDependencies": {
"": "^4.0.4",
"": "~0.9.34",
"": "^2.0.4",
"": "^2.8.2",
"": "^6.0.90",
"chai": "^4.1.2",
"chai-as-promised": "^7.1.1",
"concurrently": "2.2.0",
"cucumber": "^3.0.6",
"cucumber-html-reporter": "^3.0.4",
"jasmine": "^2.8.0",
"protractor": "^5.2.0",
"protractor-cucumber-framework": "^4.1.1",
"ts-md5": "^1.2.2",
"ts-node": "^3.3.0",
"typescript": "^2.6.1",
"update": "^0.7.4"
},
```

**Returned error:**

> Unhandled rejection TypeError: registerHandler is not a function
>   at C:\ABC\hooks\support.ts:67:5
>   at Object.defineSupportCode (C:\ABC\node_modules\cucumber\src\support_code_library_builder\index.js:20:9)
>   at Object. (C:\ABC\hooks\support.ts:60:1)

Comment: There is [a similar question in the github repo for Cucumber.js](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/issues/963). It basically says that the function `registerHandler` has been replaced by `BeforeAll`. Please check the change log for Version 3 to fix your problem.

Comment: @SaschaM78 sure thank you. Do we have something like this,    Examples DataTabkle has multiple iterations and at certain iteration i wanna do something and taking screenshots after each GIVEN WHEN THEN steps and embed em into report?